# jQuery bind unbind click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I am trying to jQuery to calculate the amount of times a ID has been clicked.
for instance if #kwick_1 is clicked once, I want it to load the video 'else' do nothing.

And I am looking at applying this throughout the function so the same goes for 2, 3, 4 etc.

How would I achieve this?

```
var timesClicked = 0;
  $('#kwick_1, #kwick_2, #kwick_3, #kwick_4, #kwick_5, #kwick_6, #kwick_7').bind('click', function(event){
   var video = $(this).find('a').attr('href'); /* bunny.mp4 */

   var clickedID = $(this).attr('id'); /* kwick_1 */
   var vid = 'vid';
   timesClicked++;

   $(this).removeAttr('id').removeAttr('class').attr('id',clickedID + vid).attr('class',clickedID + vid);
   if(timesClicked == 1) {

    $.get("video.php", { video: video, poster: 'bunny.jpg', }, function(data){
     $('.'+clickedID+vid).html(data);
    }); 

   } else {
    /* Do nothing for now */
   }
   return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to do this a bit easier, like this:

```
$('#kwick_1, #kwick_2, #kwick_3, #kwick_4, #kwick_5, #kwick_6, #kwick_7').one('click', function(event){
  var video = $(this).find('a').attr('href'), clicked = this.id + 'vid';

  $(this).attr({ id: clicked, 'class': clicked });
  $.get("video.php", { video: video, poster: 'bunny.jpg', }, function(data){
    $('.'+clicked).html(data);
  }); 
}).click(function() { return false; });
```

The rest is just optimization and cutting down on repeated code, but the idea is to bind the part you only want to happen once using [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/), then that handler will remove itself after the first execution.  Then we're binding the `return false` using [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) since that one should *always* happen.  Make sure this is bound *after* like the example above, since event handlers are run in the order they were bound.

Also you could replace your `#kwick_1, #kwick_2....` selector with `.kwick` if you could give them all a class, this above would still work and be much easier to maintain.